# Java regex search

Tags: java, regex

Could anyone help me -  I am taking preparation for my OCJP 6 exam. Here is an example:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Regex2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(args[0]);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(args[1]);
        boolean b = false;
        while(b = m.find()) {
            System.out.print(m.start() + m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

**compile:** `javac Regex2.java`

**run:** `java Regex2 "\d*" ab34ef`

**output:** `01234456`

The last index is `5`(`f`) so why in output there is `6`?

Comment: Before asking question try to search for similar questions. Simple [search for `ab34ef`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=ab34ef) gives lot of questions about this subject.

Comment: Sorry for that  I haven't found it

Answer (score 0):

It is because `\d*` can match the empty string at the end of the subject string.

The last result is:

```
offset: 6
match: ''
```

To avoid this kind of results, use `\d+` (one or more times) instead of `\d*` (zero or more times).

Note: for the same reason you obtain a match (for the empty string) at offset 0,1,4,5

```
   a   b   3   4   e   f   \0
 ^   ^   ^       ^   ^   ^
 |   |   |       |   |   |
 0   1   2       4   5   6      offset
 |   |   |       |   |   |
 +---+---|-------+---+---+----> match the empty string
         +--------------------> match '34'
```